# Integrity checks for kernel extensions in OSX

Tags: macos, kernel, kernel-extension

is there any way to check for the integrity and validity of a Kernel Extension in OS X? I have to make sure that an extension which bundle name starts with com.apple  is a real extension from Apple. Maybe a  certificate or whatever footprint that reveal if the kernel extension comes from Apple or Not.

Answer (score 1):

After working on this issue, finally I found that there is no way to check for any valid footprint for a Kernel Extension. For example, by default every machine has a large group of extensions tagged with the com.apple identifier and you virtually can use the same bundle identifier to build your own extensions so it is impossible to distinguish which extensions are from Apple and which aren't. In conclusion you could have extensions that are making phishing in your system and are secure installed without any chance to detect it and remove it. This suppose a big hole in security layer of OS X.

Comment: Most everything you wrote is incorrect. First off - System Extensions and Kernel extension need to be code-signed, and you can quite easily check their code-signing to assess their validity and origin. You can NOT code sign your own "com.apple." kernel extension to imitate apple's. In later MacOS versions (10.15 and on) a feature called "SIP" (System integrity protection) was introduced that completely removes the ability to make any change to the pre-installed MacOS system (including its Apple-branded Kernel Extensions).

Comment: @MottiShneor Note the date of the original answer. OS X Mountain Lion (10.8) had just been released earlier that year. Kernel extension code signing was only introduced with OS X Mavericks. (10.9) It's a little uncharitable to criticise the answerer for not doing time travel before writing up their answer.

Comment: I would, though, vote for you if you came out with TimeTravel mechanism... I admit I missed the date or MacOS version, as I was more focused on the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel extensions can reside either in `/Library/Extensions` or in `/System/Library/Extensions`.

To verify the validity and authenticity of a kernel extension use

```
codesign --verify -v /Library/Extensions/hp_io_enabler_compound.kext
```

in the Terminal. (the actual kernel extension is just a sample of one 3rd party kernel extension from my OS).

The kernel extension in /System/Library/Extension  are usually preinstalled, part of the MacOS itself, and cannot be changed/removed.

use `man codesign` to explore more options to extract verbose information about the extension - their entitlements, requirements, list of executables, the chain of trust, etc.